# Imageresizer.AzureReader2 doesn't work with latest Azure SDK 2.1.0.3

Tags: c#, azure, imageresizer

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I've upgraded to the latest SDK 2.1.0.3 and it seems as though ImageResizer has blown up. Are there any work arounds? Here is the details:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = xxx
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = xxx
Calling assembly : ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2, Version=3.4.0.763, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: x
LOG: Using host configuration file: x
LOG: Using machine configuration file from x
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/6038b9fb/8488b4a1/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/6038b9fb/8488b4a1/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL x
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureVirtualPathProvider..ctor(String blobStorageConnection) +0
   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin.Install(Config c) +379
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.add_plugin_by_name(String name, NameValueCollection args) +275
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.loadPluginsInternal() +402
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.LoadPlugins() +102
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config..ctor(ResizerSection config) +546
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.get_Current() +115
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.get_conf() +36
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +250
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874840
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try `Add-BindingRedirect` and it gets you nowhere (it didn't add the right redirect for me) you need to add the following into your `Web.Config`

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

        <!-- Other bindings here! -->

        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.3" newVersion="2.1.0.3"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the NuGet Package Manager Console, run the following command:

`PM> Add-BindingRedirect`

This should enable you to use a different version of the Azure SDK that was used for the last version of ImageResizer. If you installed/upgraded Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage via NuGet, this should (but may not) have been run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a file from your deployment.  Are you referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v2.1.0.0 and setting it to CopyLocal=true?

Comment: Yes but the latest version is 2.1.0.3 not 2.1.0.0