# ImageResizer AzureReader2 Plugin Nuget Error Out of the Box

Tags: imageresizer

I am getting an error when installing the ImageResizer AzureReader2 plugin. This is on a fresh install in an empty web project using Nuget to install the ImageResizer packages.

It is very similar to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611270/imageresizer-azurereader2-doesnt-work-with-latest-azure-sdk-2-1-0-3), but a binding redirect does not seem to fix the issue. I have also tried updating to 3.0 with the same issue.

Here is the stack :

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/workspace/CC3.Images/CC3.Images/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\workspace\CC3.Images\CC3.Images\bin
Calling assembly : ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2, Version=3.4.3.103, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\workspace\CC3.Images\CC3.Images\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\steve.westner\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/steve.westner/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ae2511c3/bb7d3a9/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/steve.westner/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ae2511c3/bb7d3a9/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/workspace/CC3.Images/CC3.Images/bin/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureVirtualPathProvider..ctor(String blobStorageConnection) +0
   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin.Install(Config c) +379
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.add_plugin_by_name(String name, NameValueCollection args) +275
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.loadPluginsInternal() +402
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.LoadPlugins() +102
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config..ctor(ResizerSection config) +546
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.get_Current() +115
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.get_conf() +36
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +250
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931880
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by moving to ImageResizer version 4.0 stack, which at this time is in pre-release and was not showing in the package manager console.

The following command installed everything needed :

```
Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2 -Pre
```